# Drawing directions fields

Tags: python, math

Is there a way to draw direction fields in python?

My attempt is to modify http://www.compdigitec.com/labs/files/slopefields.py giving

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import math
from subprocess import CalledProcessError, call, check_call

def dy_dx(x, y):
    try:
        # declare your dy/dx here:
        return x**2-x-2
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 1000.0

# Adjust window parameters
XMIN = -5.0
XMAX = 5.0
YMIN = -10.0
YMAX = 10.0
XSCL = 0.5
YSCL = 0.5

DISTANCE = 0.1

def main():
    fileobj = open("data.txt", "w")
    for x1 in xrange(int(XMIN / XSCL), int(XMAX / XSCL)):
        for y1 in xrange(int(YMIN / YSCL), int(YMAX / YSCL)):
            x= float(x1 * XSCL)
            y= float(y1 * YSCL)
            slope = dy_dx(x,y)
            dx = math.sqrt( DISTANCE/( 1+math.pow(slope,2) ) )
            dy = slope*dx
            fileobj.write(str(x) + " " + str(y) + " " + str(dx) + " " + str(dy) + "\n")
    fileobj.close()


    try:
        check_call(["gnuplot","-e","set terminal png size 800,600 enhanced font \"Arial,12\"; set xrange [" + str(XMIN) + ":" + str(XMAX) + "]; set yrange [" + str(YMIN) + ":" + str(YMAX) + "]; set output 'output.png'; plot 'data.txt' using 1:2:3:4 with vectors"])
    except (CalledProcessError, OSError):
        print "Error: gnuplot not found on system!"
        exit(1)
    print "Saved image to output.png"
    call(["xdg-open","output.png"])
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However the best image I get from this is.
[image]
How can I get an output that looks more like the first image? Also, how can I add the three solid lines?

Comment: Yes, [with the help of matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/quiver_demo.html).

Comment: yes! i actually made a program to do just this... will try to find it & upload it when i get home. got some really pretty pictures as a result.

Comment: slope fields a.k.a. direction fields

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use this matplotlib code as a base. Modify it for your needs.
I have updated the code to show same length arrows. The important option is to set the `angles` option of the `quiver` function, so that the arrows are correctly printed from (x,y) to (x+u,y+v) (instead of the default, which just takes into account of (u,v) when computing the angles).

It is also possible to change the axis form "boxes" to "arrows". Let me know if you need that change and I could add it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()

def vf(x, t):
    dx = np.zeros(2)
    dx[0] = 1.0
    dx[1] = x[0] ** 2 - x[0] - 2.0
    return dx


# Solution curves
t0 = 0.0
tEnd = 10.0

# Vector field
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-5, 5, 20), np.linspace(-10, 10, 20))
U = 1.0
V = X ** 2 - X - 2
# Normalize arrows
N = np.sqrt(U ** 2 + V ** 2)
U = U / N
V = V / N
plt.quiver(X, Y, U, V, angles="xy")

t = np.linspace(t0, tEnd, 100)
for y0 in np.linspace(-5.0, 0.0, 10):
    y_initial = [y0, -10.0]
    y = odeint(vf, y_initial, t)
    plt.plot(y[:, 0], y[:, 1], "-")

plt.xlim([-5, 5])
plt.ylim([-10, 10])
plt.xlabel(r"$x$")
plt.ylabel(r"$y$")
```

[image: The slope field]

Comment: How to obtain a parametrization for those colored curves?

Comment: Why is U=1? Suppose I have dy_dt = -3y+t+e**(-2*t), is U still 1?

Comment: @RicardoAcuna U=1 because of the particular example. The part that follows #Vector field is exclusively to draw the arrows in accordance to the definition of #Vector field function. Of course changing vf(t,x) should be followed by an appropriate change of U,V

Comment: @PepeToro sure but that still doesn't tell me how to translate vf(t,x) to U,V. I don't see how it's done, could you point out to to some resource that explains it, I'm at a loss. I tried a bunch of combinations and I don't get what wolfram alpha outputs.

Comment: @RicardoAcuna the U,V formulas in the program are exclusively for the arrows and are exactly equal to the equations of the vf (vector field) function. So, if you want to plot a similar picture, say for $(x',y')=(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y))$ write $(U,V)=(f_1(X,Y),f_2(X,Y)$. Note that I use big $(X,Y)$ to denote the coordinates of the mesh. Then, you use $N$ to normalise the arrows, so that all of them have the same length. Therefore, it is important to note that the picture you get is for a normalised vector field in which only the direction is shown but not the velocity itself. Hope this helps.

Comment: In your vf function, dx holds [dx/dx, dy/dx] right? So for all differential equations,  dx[0] = 1, while dx[1] = x[0]**2 + 1 if (dy/dx = x^2 + 1). and if (dy/dx = x^2 + y + 1), ithen dx[1] = x[0]**2 + y[0] + 1 right?

Comment: This script is wrong, because of the way `quiver` draw the angles of the arrow. The default setting is angles="uv" which makes so that the angles only depends on u and v. The correct graphics can be obtained with the angles="xy" which makes so that the arrows are from (x,y) to (x+u, y+u).

Answer (score 2):

I had a lot of fun making one of these as a hobby project using pygame. I plotted the slope at each pixel, using shades of blue for positive and shades of red for negative. Black is for undefined. This is `dy/dx = log(sin(x/y)+cos(y/x))`:

[image: dy/dx=log(sin(x/y)+cos(y/x)]

You can zoom in & out - here is zoomed in on the middle upper part here:

[image: as above zoomed in]

and also click on a point to graph the line going through that point:

[image: and as it is such so also as such is it unto you]

It's just 440 lines of code, so [here is the .zip of all the files](https://mega.co.nz/#!4Q8k3IDa!VT0U4xiF0fGfuUG6gad9TSqCQwIUAiH94ddfB5gxSZs). I guess I'll excerpt relevant bits here.

The equation itself is input as a valid Python expression in a string, e.g. `"log(sin(x/y)+cos(y/x))"`. This is then `compile`d. This function here graphs the color field, where `self.func.eval()` gives the `dy/dx` at the given point. The code is a bit complicated here because I made it render in stages - first 32x32 blocks, then 16x16, etc. - to make it snappier for the user.

```
def graphcolorfield(self, sqsizes=[32,16,8,4,2,1]):
    su = ScreenUpdater(50)
    lastskip = self.xscreensize
    quitit = False
    for squaresize in sqsizes:
        xsquaresize = squaresize
        ysquaresize = squaresize

        if squaresize == 1:
            self.screen.lock()
        y = 0
        while y <= self.yscreensize:
            x = 0
            skiprow = y%lastskip == 0
            while x <= self.xscreensize:
                if skiprow and x%lastskip==0:
                    x += squaresize
                    continue

                color = (255,255,255)
                try:
                    m = self.func.eval(*self.ct.untranscoord(x, y))
                    if m >= 0:
                        if m < 1:
                            c = 255 * m
                            color = (0, 0, c)
                        else:
                            #c = 255 - 255 * (1.0/m)
                            #color = (c, c, 255)
                            c = 255 - 255 * (1.0/m)
                            color = (c/2.0, c/2.0, 255)

                    else:
                        pm = -m
                        if pm < 1:
                            c = 255 * pm
                            color = (c, 0, 0)
                        else:
                            c = 255 - 255 * (1.0/pm)
                            color = (255, c/2.0, c/2.0)                        
                except:
                    color = (0, 0, 0)

                if squaresize > 1:
                    self.screen.fill(color, (x, y, squaresize, squaresize))
                else:
                    self.screen.set_at((x, y), color)

                if su.update():
                    quitit = True
                    break

                x += xsquaresize

            if quitit:
                break

            y += ysquaresize

        if squaresize == 1:
            self.screen.unlock()
        lastskip = squaresize
        if quitit:
            break
```

This is the code which graphs a line through a point:

```
def _grapheqhelp(self, sx, sy, stepsize, numsteps, color):
    x = sx
    y = sy
    i = 0

    pygame.draw.line(self.screen, color, (x, y), (x, y), 2)
    while i < numsteps:
        lastx = x
        lasty = y

        try:
            m = self.func.eval(x, y)
        except:
            return

        x += stepsize            
        y = y + m * stepsize

        screenx1, screeny1 = self.ct.transcoord(lastx, lasty)
        screenx2, screeny2 = self.ct.transcoord(x, y)

        #print "(%f, %f)-(%f, %f)" % (screenx1, screeny1, screenx2, screeny2)

        try:
            pygame.draw.line(self.screen, color,
                             (screenx1, screeny1),
                             (screenx2, screeny2), 2)
        except:
            return

        i += 1

    stx, sty = self.ct.transcoord(sx, sy)
    pygame.draw.circle(self.screen, color, (int(stx), int(sty)), 3, 0)
```

And it runs backwards & forwards starting from that point:

```
def graphequation(self, sx, sy, stepsize=.01, color=(255, 255, 127)):
    """Graph the differential equation, given the starting point sx and sy, for length
    length using stepsize stepsize."""
    numstepsf = (self.xrange[1] - sx) / stepsize
    numstepsb = (sx - self.xrange[0]) / stepsize

    self._grapheqhelp(sx, sy,  stepsize, numstepsf, color)
    self._grapheqhelp(sx, sy, -stepsize, numstepsb, color)
```

I never got around to drawing actual lines because the pixel approach looked too cool.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your values for the parameters to this:

```
XSCL = .2
YSCL = .2
```

These parameters determine how many points are sampled on the axes.

---

As per your comment, you'll need to also plot the functions for which the derivation dy_dx(x, y) applies.

Currently, you're only calculating and plotting the slope lines as calculated by your function dy_dx(x,y).  You'll need to find (in this case 3) functions to plot in addition to the slope.

Start by defining a function:

```
def f1_x(x):
    return x**3-x**2-2x;
```

and then, in your loop, you'll have to also write the desired values for the functions into the fileobj file.

Comment: Thanks. 0.5 seems roughly right. It still doesn't look as good to me (there is no axis for example) but in any case, do you know how to add the three solid lines?  My preference would be to do the whole thing in python without gnuplot if that is possible.