# How do I generate a vector field plot for logistic equation K = 1 using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, numeric, differential-equations

I'm going through Strogatz's Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos and I've hit a snag in chapter 2 Exercise 2.8.1. (Educator flag: I've graduated so this isn't for a class, I'm just trying to get back into the numerical solving of differential equations) It's a pretty simple differential equation and I can plot individual solution curves given different initial conditions but I'm trying to use quiver or streamplot to superimpose individual solutions on top of the vector field.

My problem is in understanding how to translate the vector field plots for similar problems in the dy/dx form found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18832763/1429450) over to the dx/dt form that's primarily tackled in Strogatz's book.

Given that the x vector that's defined in the logistic function is only one dimensional I'm having a hard time reasoning out how express the u and v flows in quiver or streamplot since the problem only seems to have a u flow. It's probably super easy and is being over-thought but any guidance or assistance would be much appreciated!

So far I have the following:

```
# 2.8.1
# Plot the vector field and some trajectories for xdot = x(1-x) given 
# some different initial conditions for the logistic equation with carrying 
# capacity K = 1

# dx/dt = x(1-x)  

# Imports:
from __future__ import division
from scipy import *
import numpy as np
import pylab
import matplotlib as mp
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt  
import sys
import math as mt

def logistic(x,t):
    return np.array([x[0]*(1-x[0])])

def RK4(t0 = 0, x0 = np.array([1]), t1 = 5 , dt = 0.01, ng = None):  
    tsp = np.arange(t0, t1, dt)
    Nsize = np.size(tsp)
    X = np.empty((Nsize, np.size(x0)))
    X[0] = x0

    for i in range(1, Nsize):
        k1 = ng(X[i-1],tsp[i-1])
        k2 = ng(X[i-1] + dt/2*k1, tsp[i-1] + dt/2)
        k3 = ng(X[i-1] + dt/2*k2, tsp[i-1] + dt/2)
        k4 = ng(X[i-1] + dt*k3, tsp[i-1] + dt)
        X[i] = X[i-1] + dt/6*(k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)
    return X

def tplot():
    t0 = 0
    t1 = 10
    dt = 0.02
    tsp = np.arange(t0,t1,dt)
    X = RK4(x0 = np.array([2]), t1 = 10,dt = 0.02, ng = logistic)
    Y = RK4(x0 = np.array([0.01]), t1 = 10,dt = 0.02, ng = logistic)
    Z = RK4(x0 = np.array([0.5]), t1 = 10,dt = 0.02, ng = logistic)
    P = RK4(x0 = np.array([3]), t1 = 10,dt = 0.02, ng = logistic)
    Q = RK4(x0 = np.array([0.1]), t1 = 10,dt = 0.02, ng = logistic)
    R = RK4(x0 = np.array([1.5]), t1 = 10,dt = 0.02, ng = logistic)
    O = RK4(x0 = np.array([1]), t1 = 10,dt = 0.02, ng = logistic)
    pylab.figure()
    pylab.plot(tsp,X)
    pylab.plot(tsp,Y)
    pylab.plot(tsp,Z)
    pylab.plot(tsp,P)
    pylab.plot(tsp,Q)
    pylab.plot(tsp,R)
    pylab.plot(tsp,O)
    pylab.title('Logistic Equation - K=1')
    pylab.xlabel('Time')
    pylab.ylabel('Xdot')
    pylab.show()

print tplot()
```

[image here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/exeyh84mx8qb2x5/2_8_1fig.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To graph a slope from a derivative (like, *dx/dt*), you can first find *dx/dt*, and then use a fixed *dt* to calculate *dx*.  Then, at each *(t, x)* of interest, plot the little line segment from *(t,x)* to *(t+dt, x+dx)*.

Here's an example for your equation *dx/dt = x(1-x)*.  (The Strogatz picture doesn't have arrowheads so I removed them too.)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

times = np.linspace(0, 10,  20)
x = np.linspace(0 ,2, 20)
T, X = np.meshgrid(times, x)   # make a grid that roughly matches the Strogatz grid  

dxdt = X*(1-X)            # the equation of interest
dt = .5*np.ones(X.shape)  # a constant value (.5 is just so segments don't run into each other -- given spacing of times array
dx = dxdt * dt            # given dt, now calc dx for the line segment

plt.quiver(T, X, dt, dx, headwidth=0., angles='xy', scale=15.)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Read the what not to comment thingy, so instead of thanks I'll just say that superimposing your slope field on top of the previously plotted trajectories as well as the addition of plt.streamplot(T, A, dt, dx) have successfully created the busiest plot ever!

Comment: @wonkybadonk: one thing I wondered when writing this was that it seemed that my slopes, especially below x=1., were about half of what is shown in the book.  So I wonder, do the slopes of your streamlines match the slopes calculated from this method.  (My guess is they're exaggerated in the book, but an uncertain.  Also I have a 20yo copy of the book too, so maybe they've changed the slopes in the newer versions.)

Comment: interestingly enough the streamlines and the plotted trajectories come in to approach the value of the carrying capacity at a steeper slope than the plotted vector field when all superimposed in the same figure. I don't really understand why though. https://www.dropbox.com/s/2h8crg3tfsr89qy/strogatz_2_8_1.png?dl=0

Comment: @wonkybadonk: OK, fixed it in code and plot.  In quiver need `angles='xy'`.

Answer (score 0):

wonkybadonk: For the difference in slope of the plotted trajectories and the plotted vector field seem to be due to the fact that your vector field are not steep enough. Make sure that 
         dx = dxdt*dt; (point by point multiplication, not a dot product)
         and that you added "angles='xy'" as a quiver argument. (see tom10 post).